# Configure owner and permissions for upstart log files

Tags: permissions, upstart, logging

When logging an upstart job with the standard `console log` stanza, can the resulting log files in `/var/log/upstart` be configured to be written with a mode or owner other than the default?

Comment: By 'mode' do you mean permissions?

Comment: yes, permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, upstart runs as root, and is in charge of creating the log files. You'll want to do your own logging if you want to control the owners and permissions. You can just direct the output/stderr of all of the commands to a log file if that is what you want.

Comment: Looks to be the case, though not the answer I was hoping for. The whole interaction of upstart and logrotate by default in 12.04 seems to be a bit of a mess.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Took me a  it to figure out, just make sure its not the same logfile as the root log file if it is part of the upstart job with `setuid` and `getuid` set.